# IOS Pan gesture animation from right to left

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, uiviewanimation, uiviewanimationtransition

[image: Image101]

[image: Image102]

I want to slide this options which are in form of button from right to left shown in above image101. After sliding it another options comes with new new text on the screen as shown in image102. So the text and options in A,B,C both should slide from right to left and other thing the remaining circles should have small radius according to the selected circle. But I am little bit weak in animation/transitions so what should I do in this situation. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Try this git library https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel. This is very helpful.

Comment: @jayeshThanki  Thank you for the reply will check this hope it would help me.